# Laplace smoothing and naive bayes

Tags: naivebayes, smoothing

If I want to use naive bayes with laplace smoothing and therefore add 1 to probabilities with the value of 0, what does this mean for probabilities which have the actual value of 1?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you should probably ask this at [Cross validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), as Stackoverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://stats.stackexchange.com/.